# Using Zclip in Kendoui Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, zclip

I am trying to make something where you click a small icon that is part of a column template and it copies the contents of that cell:

```
var toCopy = '';
$(document).on('mouseup', '.copy-to-clipboard', function() {
    toCopy = $(this).parent().prev().html();
    $('.copy-to-clipboard').zclip({
        path: ROOT + 'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: $(this).parent().prev().html()
    });
})
```

Template:

```
function defaultTemplate(fieldName) {
    return '<span>#='+fieldName+'#</span><div class="pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip copy-to-clipboard" title="Copy cell contents to clipboard"></i></div>';
}
```

However, I need to bind Zclip to the icons when the grid loads, not on document ready like the tutorials:

```
$('.k-grid').data("kendoGrid").bind("dataBound", function() {
    $('.copy-to-clipboard').zclip({
        path: ROOT + 'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: $(this).parent().prev().html()
    });
});
```

But nothing happens.

How can I get this to work in the grid?